# My tkinter program to modify a label when a button is pressed is malfunctioning (closed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, windows-10

I'm trying to create a tkinter program to modify a label when a button is pressed. It may sound simple, but my code is not working. Python doesn't show any error, it just freezes/crashes and doesn't respond. I am using pycharm on windows 10.
I have copied all my code and pasted it below:

This part of my code doesn't matter much, but it may be useful:

```
import socket
import mmstraphGL
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage
import numpy as keras
import time
import waiting
import pyglet
import tkinter as mykinter
import sys
import pyautogui as tkinter

testmat1 = [1, 2]
testmat2 = [2, 3]
print(keras.dot(testmat1, testmat2))


def socket_get():
    return socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())


copyrightx = sys.copyright

scwidth, scheight = tkinter.size()
widit = scwidth * ((4 - 0.1 + (1 - 1)) / 5)
hihit = scheight * ((4 - 0.1 + (1 - 1)) / 5)
ww = ((10 - 2) / ((6 * 1) + (2 - 1))) * widit
hh = (9 / (9 - 1)) * hihit
diwit = int(ww)
tihit = int(hh)

rootgeo = (str((str(int((5 / 5) * scwidth))) + 'x' + (str(int((5 / 5) * scheight)))))

root: Tk = mykinter.Tk()
root.geometry(rootgeo)

iconx = mykinter.PhotoImage(file='icon.png.png')
root.iconphoto(False, iconx)

x_Left = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - diwit / 2)
y_Top = int(root.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - tihit / 2)
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x_Left, y_Top))

root.title("T squared")
root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)
bagr = mykinter.PhotoImage(file='converted.gif')
bagger = mykinter.Label(root, image=bagr, height=tihit * 2, width=scwidth * 2).place(x=-776, y=0)


def center(win):
    win.update_idletasks()
    width = win.winfo_width()
    frm_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    win_width = width + 2 * frm_width
    height = win.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
    win_height = height + titlebar_height + frm_width
    x = win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - win_width // 2
    y = win.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - win_height // 2
    win.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    win.deiconify()


center(root)


def create_font(self):
    pyglet.font.add_file(self)


def fonts():
    create_font('good times rg.ttf')
    create_font('dindin.ttf')
    create_font('f4o8nt.ttf')
    create_font('minefalse.ttf')


lvl = 1

fonts()

frame12 = mykinter.Frame(highlightbackground='#283747', master=root, highlightthickness=10, relief='raised')
frame12.place(x=0, y=0)
```

The part of my code that *really* makes it malfunction is this:

```
label12 = mmstraphGL.lab(True, 'underline', "Text here", 55, "Good Times Rg", '#EBDEF0', True, True, '#E74C3C', 0, 0,
                         [7, mykinter.RAISED], root, 500,
                         500,
                         ((1.2 / 2) * diwit), 35)
label24 = mykinter.Label(text="Text here text here", font=('.', 27), fg='#2E4053',
                         borderwidth=9.5, relief=mykinter.RAISED,
                         master=root, padx=((2.2 / 6.3) * (1 / 2) * diwit), pady=40)
label24.place(x=0, y=297)

label48 = mykinter.Label(
    text="Text here text here text here text here",
    font=('Omotenashi 2', 22), fg='#EBDEF0', bg='#212F3C', borderwidth=6.5, relief=mykinter.RAISED, master=root,
    padx=((5.4 / 6.3) * (1 / 2) * diwit), pady=25)
label48.place(x=0, y=460)
label192 = mykinter.Label(text="textey", font=('.', 8), fg='#2E4053',
                          borderwidth=9.5, relief=mykinter.RAISED,
                          master=root, padx=0, pady=0)
label192.place(x=760, y=920)


def prmp():
    global label192
    label192.config(fg='#FF0000')


nottub96 = mmstraphGL.tubn(mykinter.RAISED, True, "bold underline", False, '#EBDEF0', '#E74C3C',
                           "Make textey red", 10, mykinter.NORMAL, prmp(),
                           'Serreria Sobria',
                           '#283747', True, True, '#EBDEF0', ((8.2 / 12) * (diwit / 2)), 795, 9, root, 250, 1600, 5, 2)


def waitfuncs():
    def check(murda):
        if murda:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def wait_until(delegate, timeout: int):
        end = time.time() + timeout
        while time.time() < end:
            if delegate():
                return True
            else:
                time.sleep(0.0067)
        return False


root.mainloop()
```

Few notes:

1. I know that mmstraphGL is no module, I made it on my own.
2. All the fonts I am using are in the same directory and working properly.

When I run my code sometimes it crashes and sometimes it shows that the label textey(`label192`) is red by default, even before I click the button. Please help. I'd be happy clarify any doubts about my question in the comments. Why is it red as soon as the program loads? Can you please run it on your machine and tell me if it still doesn't work? Is there any error in the code? The text is red even before the function `prmp()` is called.

Also, if it helps, here is the code for the tubn class in mmstraphGL:

```
class tubn:
    def __init__(self, sigh, downlinspace, cascsheet, actsdef, actbg, actfg, txt, fomtsize, defstate, cmd, fomtype,
                 hhexx_fg,
                 borderstate, hhexx_bg_truestate, hhexx_bg, yex_pos, why_pos, bordr, masta, hght, wdth, xp, yp):
        if actsdef:
            if (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, bg=hhexx_bg, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, bd=bordr, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, bg=hhexx_bg, bd=bordr, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt), relief=sigh, font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg),
                                       height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(
                    height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), x=yex_pos, y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, bg=hhexx_bg, relief=sigh, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, bg=hhexx_bg, bd=bordr, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt), relief=sigh, font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet),
                                       fg=str(hhexx_fg),
                                       height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(
                    height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), x=yex_pos, y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, relief=sigh, bd=bordr, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
        elif not actsdef:
            if (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(relief=sigh, state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, bg=hhexx_bg, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, bd=bordr, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == False):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, relief=sigh, bg=hhexx_bg, bd=bordr, master=masta,
                                       text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, relief=sigh, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == False) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, bg=hhexx_bg, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == True) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, relief=sigh, command=lambda: cmd, activebackground=actbg,
                                       activeforeground=actfg, bg=hhexx_bg, bd=bordr, master=masta, text=str(txt),
                                       font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet), fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                       width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp, pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2),
                                                                                         width=int(int(wdth) / 2),
                                                                                         x=yex_pos,
                                                                                         y=why_pos)
            elif (hhexx_bg_truestate == False) and (borderstate == True) and (downlinspace == True):
                tubb = mykinter.Button(state=defstate, command=lambda: cmd, activeforeground=actfg, bd=bordr,
                                       master=masta, relief=sigh, text=str(txt), font=(fomtype, fomtsize, cascsheet),
                                       fg=str(hhexx_fg), height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), padx=xp,
                                       pady=yp).place(height=int(int(hght) / 2), width=int(int(wdth) / 2), x=yex_pos,
                                                      y=why_pos)

        self.text = txt
        self.size = fomtsize
        self.font = fomtype
        self.color = hhexx_fg
        self.x_position = yex_pos
        self.y_position = why_pos
        self.border = bordr
        self.height = hght
        self.width = wdth

    def update(self, configee):
        tubb.config(configee)

    def remember(self):
        tubb.destroy()
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My doubt has been cleared now! You don't need to bother!

Comment: The Label is red from the beginning, because you're calling the function `prmp` immediately after defining it - that's what `prmp()` *means*.  Perhaps you just want to pass `prmp` (the function itself, rather than the result of calling it) to `mmstraphGL.tubn()`.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes. I want the text to turn red when the button is clicked. Otherwise, it should stay normal and not red. It should only turn red when the button is clicked.

Comment: @jasonharper I edited the post and added the code for the tubn class in mmstraphGL, if that can help you in helping me.

Comment: You've partly solved my problem. I tried not calling the function and changed prmp() to prmp. Now, the text isn't red. But it still doesn't work; when I click the button it doesn't do anything. Any help?

Comment: `tubn()` is never actually calling the command being passed to it.  The Buttons should be created with `command=cmd` - if you insist on doing it with a lambda, it would be `command=lambda: cmd()`.

Comment: I *am* doing it with ```lambda: cmd()```

Comment: No, I only see `lambda: cmd` in your code.  When that lambda gets called (by clicking a button), it just references `cmd`, it doesn't actually call it.

Comment: Got it! Let me try, hold up 1 sec...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help! You solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a question: It closes without console log? If your python file have the ext: *.pyw* try to change  it to *.py* for having the console near. And document it if crashes with. By the way, if they don't have logs on terminal. It's means that you are having a filtering problem with the function:

```
def remember(self):
        tubb.destroy()
```

I searched in the code and any button calls that def. Try to erase those lines and try again.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but my doubt was already solved in the comments. I marked the post as closed and also edited it to say that you didn't need to answer. But thanks for trying to help :)